# ViewGroup_instance.addView(View_instance), how a subclass can accept a super class instance?

Tags: android, android-view, viewgroup

What I think about this method:

`ViewGroup`, which is `subclass` of `View`, can not accept `View_instance` because of the inheritance hierarchy, so `ViewGroup_instance` is working as `container` for `View_instance`.

It is correct?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to say?

Comment: i am asking that , can  View_subclass ( ViewGroup ) add a View_superclass ( View ) in itself , is there any dispute in inheritance rule

Comment: because , ViewGroup is subclass of View ..... i am talking about : 
, i am cosidering add() as a "subclass instance = new super_class ()"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ViewGroup.addView()` methods have nothing to do at all with inheritance, those methods are just part of the `ViewGroup` implementation(besides the inherited behavior from `View`) to allow the adding of child views. The `addView()` methods use the `View` super class to allow the addition of any `View`(simple view or layout grouping views).

Comment: @Luksporg .... i know that this is wrong , but i am facing problem in this question ( so i am redirecting you to this page ) .
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15540265/how-to-restrict-the-webview-inside-in-android-program