# How to restrict the WebView inside in android program

Tags: android, android-webview

i want to restrict `webView's` `limit` inside some `pixels` which  is have declared at the time of `webView` initialization .

```
View insertPoint = findViewById(R.id.layout);

WebView web = new WebView(this) ;
web.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
int lHeight = 200 ;
int lWidth = 200 ;


( (ViewGroup) insertPoint ).addView(web, lWidth, lHeight) ;

web.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

Edited :

Full Screen is taken by that `WebView` , it is not residing inside `200px*200px` .

Edited :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/layout" >



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Full Screen is taken by that WebView , it is not residing inside 200px*200px .

Comment: if possible post complete code

Comment: @Abhijit .... please see Luksprog , comment !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work if you also add the line:

```
web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Otherwise your code will start the browser(which is full screen). If you click BACK for example you should see your gray box.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code for setting the height width :

```
            WebView w =new WebView(this);
            LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            w.setLayoutParams(lp);
            w.getLayoutParams().width = 200;
            w.getLayoutParams().height = 200;
            ( (ViewGroup) insertPoint ).addView(w) ;
```

Comment: please try in your xml set height and width in webview to 200 dp

Answer (score 0):

Yes your code is working check `layout xml` file weather you have declared your `layout_width`,`layout_height` `match_parent` or `fill_parent` if so then change it to `wrap_content` it will work .

put this layout instead of your layout if it works then there is nothing wrong in your code
otherwise u have problem in ur xml.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/layout"   >


</LinearLayout>
```

Activity class

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        loadView();

    }
    public void loadView(){
        View insertPoint = findViewById(R.id.layout);

        WebView web = new WebView(this) ;
        web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        web.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        int lHeight = 200 ;
        int lWidth = 200 ;


        ((ViewGroup) insertPoint) .addView(web, lWidth, lHeight) ;

        web.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

    }
```

Comment: please , Can your provide me some code & if i understand you correctly than ... i have implemented layout_height & width to wrap_content also i am posting my Liner_layout xml file .

Comment: i have editated my answar tell me weather its working or not.

Comment: Sorry , still web_page is taking the whole space , but ... is this working in your machine , or there is problem with my AVD , which is of 240*320 pixels !

Comment: 1024 * 768 is your resolution does not matter check ur android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" things

Comment: i have copy pasted your code , still not working ... its time pick a gun and shoot my machine !

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26603/discussion-between-tushar-and-abhijit)